# Java script code error (beginner level)

Tags: javascript

Where is the error in my JavaScript code?

```
var friends = {
  bill: {
    firstName: 'Bill',
    lastName: 'Gates',
    number: 23123,
    address: ['One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052']
  },
  steve: {
    firstName: 'Steve',
    lastName: 'Trueman',
    number: 123123,
    address: ['One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052']
  }
};
/*
var list = function(friends) {

  for (var firstName in friends) {
    console.log(firstName)
      // Use object[key] to access
      // the corresponding value
  }
}
*/
var search = function() {
  for (var firstName in friends) {
    if (firstName === 'Steve') {
      console.log(friends[steve]);
      return friends[steve];
    } else {
      console.log("not cool")
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. be advised that SO is not a riddles website, dropping your code ans asking why it doesnt work is off topic. at least isolate the problematic block and post what error you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `search()` function needs executed somewhere ...

```
search();
```

Here's what I would change to ...

```
var search = function () {
    for (var f in friends) {
        if (friends[f].firstName === 'Steve') {
            console.log(friends[f]);
            return friends[f];
        } else {
            console.log("not cool")
        };
    }
};
```

... note the `f in frients`, this acts like an index on the array allowing for (later) `friends[f]` and `friends[f].firstname` as proper references.

Comment: `friends` is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

The loop in the function doesn't do what you think.

Using `for(var firstName in friends)` doesn't mean that you get the `firstName` property from each object in `friends`. You will get the key for each object in `friends`, and that key is put in a variable named `firstName`.

With your current data, the variable will get the value `"bill"` in the first iteration, then `"steve"` in the second iteration.

Also, the action taken for not finding anything (logging "not cool") is premature. As you are doing it in the loop, you will get one of those for each person until you find the match. Determining that nothing was found would be done after the loop, i.e. when all items in the object has been checked.

A more useful version of the function would be:

```
function search(name) {
  for (var key in friends) {
    var friend = friends[key];
    if (friend.firstName === name) {
        return friend;
    };
  }
  return null;
};
```

Usage:

```
var f = search('Steve');
if (f != null) {
  // found steve
} else {
  // not found
}
```